Error: Unable to launch browser, error message: Failed to launch the browser process! undefined
I'm trying to run multiple puppeteer instances using node cluster. The puppeteer instances will spawn up on incoming request to my api endpoint which is built using express.
app.js
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/", route);

const numOfCpus = availableParallelism(); // 4

if (cluster.isPrimary) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numOfCpus; ++i) {
    const worker = cluster.fork();
    worker.on("exit", (code) => {
      console.log(`Worker with pid ${code} stopped`);
    });
  }
} else {
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started at PORT:${port}`);
  });
}


handleRequest.js (api endpoint)
const handleRequest = async (req, res) => {
  const {
    body: { url, key },
  } = req;

  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
  res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

  let cluster, result;
  try {
    cluster = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      userDataDir,
      args: [
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--no-zygote",
        "--devtools-flags=disable",
      ],
    });
     const page = await cluster.newPage();
     await page.goto(url, {waitUntil:"networkidle0"});
     await page.screenshot();
     // do more things
    await browser.close();
    } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
    if (cluster) cluster.close();
   }
  };


Now the main issue
When I tried to do concurrency test on my endpoint using $ ab -n 50 -c 10 -p postdata.txt -T application/json http://localhost:5000/enpoint. I got Unable to launch browser, error message: Failed to launch the browser process! undefined for most of the incoming requests.
I thought may be it's resource issue. So, I cut down worker numbers by half(not working). Also made only two concurrent request at once (not working). It's only working if no concurrent requests are being made.
puppeteer-cluster can be a replacement for this. But I want to know why this is happening.

The issue is related to Windows only I think. I switched to Ubuntu and it's working fine.
